# Remove Duplicate and show Unique With Count in Div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to count the total number of "0's" against label "a", and count the total number of "1's" against label "a". and Count the total number of "1's" against label "b".

Div:Input1

```
[   
    {y: 0 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 0 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 1 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 1 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 1, label: 'b'}, 
    {y: 1, label: 'b'}, 
    {y: 1, label: 'b'}

]
```

Div:Input2

```
[   
    {y: 0 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 0 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 1 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 1 ,  label: 'a'}, 
    {y: 1, label: 'b'}, 
    {y: 1, label: 'b'}, 
    {y: 1, label: 'b'}

]
```

I want the output, with duplicates removed"
The output i expect from the about input is:

Div output1: This will calculate only the "1's" of div input1

```
[   
        {y: 2,  label: 'a'},
        {y: 3,  label: 'b'}, 

    ]
```

Div output2: This will calculate only the "0's" of div input2

```
[   
        {y: 2,  label: 'a'},
        {y: 0,  label: 'b'}, 

    ]
```

Comment: your question is confusing! plz rephrase your question!

Comment: @Tim I have modified my question for better understanding.. please let me know your suggestion

Comment: @Tim waiting for reply....

Comment: let me know if you dont get it, or need mroe comments! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup is possible!

This problem is known as **aggregation** problem, usually you will use map and reduce to aggregate the value

```
//data is the your value array
data.filter(function(item) {
    //filter the data with the condition
    return !((item.y === 1) && (item.label === 'a'));
}).reduce(function(result, value) {
    let label = value.label;

    //Check if the label exists?, if yes, add the y value
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if(result[i].label === label) {
            result[i].y++;

            return result;
        }
    }

    //If label not exist add new label into the array and init the y value
    result.push({
        label: label,
        y: 1
    })

    return result;
}, []); // Init an empty array
```